# Prevent Windows 10 from transferring keyboard setting from one PC to another

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I have desktop PC and I use US keyboard layout. Recently I bought laptop with UK keyboard (I know, but discount was good so I couldn't resist).

Now what happens is that whatever keyboard I choose for laptop (ENG - UK) Windows 10 automatically sets that layout to any other PC I use and where I am logged in with my Microsoft credentials (@live) and that is on any other PC I use at home or at work. Opposite is also true when I revert from UK to US on my desktop PCs it is set that way on laptop as well.- Any idea how to stop "backup" & "transfer" of this specific setting?

**As it seems I wasn't clear enough with OP here is additional explanation:**
Moreover if I delete US layout on laptop Windows delete it on BOTH Laptop AND PC. Same for UK layout. If I delete it on PC it deletes it on Laptop as well. Whatever I do on one machine it goes on every other machine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to delete the layout you don't want to use from both machines?

Comment: I won't go - if I delete US layout on laptop Windows delete it on BOTH PC. Same for UK layout. If I delete it on PC it deletes it on laptop as well.

Comment: Why don't you just disable syncing your settings entirely?

Comment: Try disabling the "Language preferences" sync settings. See [Understanding the New Sync Settings in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @DavidPostill please post your comment as answer so I can accept it as solution. I disabled "Language preferences" and that solved problem. Thanks!

Comment: @NenadBulatovic Answer added :)

Comment: @Ramhound Why are you suggesting a brute force approach when there is a more subtle solution? ;p

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, don't have my machine in front of me, should have checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Prevent Windows 10 from transferring keyboard settings from one PC to another?

You can disable the synchronisation of "Language preferences":

- Go to "Accounts" > "Sync your settings"
- Set "Language preferences" to "Off"

This will prevent the synchronisation of your keyboard settings (as well as other language specific settings).

Source [Understanding the New Sync Settings in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/)